# Empty table data and reset IDENTITY columns

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I created a database in SQL Server with a couple of tables. I ran some tests and now am ready to deploy my solution, problem is, there is all sorts of data in the tables. I want to delete every row of all the tables created with my tests and put back the primary keys to zero. I tried delete which doesn't reset the primary keys index, and drop simply destroyed the table.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try `TRUNCATE TABLE` which deletes all rows and resets identity seeds. However you will have to execute in a certain order if you have foreign keys. In which case you will need to delete from the child tables first, or drop the constraints and re-add them.

Also note that if you are using `IDENTITY` you really shouldn't expect the numbers to mean anything, or to be generated forever without gaps. You shouldn't care whether it starts at 1 vs. 22 or 65 - can you explain why the identity values need to be reset?

Comment: A belated reply to your counterquestion - we're in the exact same situation as the poster and our use case is that the client has provided an Excel spreadsheet for import into a SQL database (table per sheet, row per record) where they've used an ID column in each sheet to relate records from sheet A to B to C. The IDs themselves are meaningless, but the relationships between them are important.

Answer (score 9):

From: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/

To set the value of the next ID to be 1, I can use this command:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: Good sir, you saved a lot of time, Thank you.

Comment: On SQL Server version 2014 the RESEED is the actual next identity key:
This: DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, RESEED, 0)
Results in a next Key of 0