# Reset IDENTITY columns Manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I see multiple topics on this issue, where you have tested with a database, and now want to reset the ids.
There are a lot of ways to do this with codes, but isn't there a way to do this manually in sql server 2008? So to just go to your table(/content) and reset the id's + clear the values.
Atm, I can only go into my contents and delete these, but my id's still remain.

[Similar Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384776/empty-table-data-and-reset-identity-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically - you need to run the [DBCC checkident](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) to get the database engine to reseed.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('<your table>', RESEED, <new seed>);
```

Comment: What I was looking for, was something like: go to your table, right mouse click, and click on the option 'reseed table'.  
But I assume that there is no such thing?!

Could you please explain to me, where I should place this small script? I only use sql server for standard purposes, so I'm not very familiar with the works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On SQL server, if you are deleting all data and resetting an identity column, I would use Truncate
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea, I don't know how this would really work in the real,  but you could create a `Create Table Script` if you are going to clear the Table anyway, just Drop and Re-Create the table.  if you are only going to do it once it shouldn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that there is no manual way to reseed your table.
The only way is to go to: New Query, and type like Allan S. Hansen is saying:
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('', RESEED, );

where if my tabel is tblSporen from my database: BRADY, my query would be:
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('BRADY.dbo.tblSporen', RESEED, 0);